# Какой придумать себе проект/портал, чтобы максимально развить навыки веб-технологий?

Tags: веб-программирование, php, html5, javascript

WEB Какой придумать себе проект/портал, чтобы максимально развить навыки веб-технологий?

Comment: давайте сначала определимся, что такое веб-технологии

Comment: @Etki в направление Front-end и Back-end...
html5,js,nodejs,php....

Comment: @Анатолийй, я боюсь, что с такой конкретикой данные вам советы канут в никуда. На бэкенд у вас выбор только из одной опции из двух - nodejs или php, комбинировать их - ваша разработка загнется еще раньше, чем на одном из них. Но если хотите сложный проект - сделайте обработчик джипегов, на фронте предварительная обработка, на бэке очереди, кромсатор, поглощающий эти очереди, формирование отчетов за неделю.

Comment: Всё зависит от уже имеющихся знаний/навыков. Попробуйте начинать с написания простейших CMS, интернет-магазина, файлохранилище/фотохостинг.

Comment: думаю, сайчас можно писать свою социальную сеть, которая порвет всех:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> По моему субъективному мнению, тут 2 варианта.

1. Если Вы желаете развиваться в творческом направлении, "велком" в "геймдев", начинаем писать браузерную игру, приложение для VK. По мере хода разработки, прокачиваем навыки во frontend разработке, делая приложение более интерактивным.
2. Вторая ветка это "Интерпрайз" приложение, автоматизация неких бизнес процессов. Тут требуется выделить, повседневный рутинный процесс (пусть даже в несколько этапов) и попытать его автоматизировать. Если вы студент, начните с расписания занятий, календаря событий, возможно в скором времени это перерастет в CRM систему.

> Итог. Первый вариант прокачает интерактивность, второй вариант автоматизацию и понимание бизнес-процессов. Первый вариант для саморазвития/самореализации, второй вариант для получения "бабла". Старайтесь развиваться в этих направлениях. И !обязательно! "валидируйте" вводимую пользователем информацию на стороне сервера ыыыы. Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

Социальные сети, приложения, агрегация данных, системы поиска и искусственного интеллекта. Это наиболее трендовое на сегодняшний день. Список большой, выбирайте то, чем больше нравится заниматься, остальное вторично.